# Escape single quotes in long directory name then pass it to xargs [Bash 3.2.48]

Tags: bash, sed, awk, pipe, xargs

In my directory I have subfolders, and I want to list all directories like this:

```
-  ./subfolder
-  ./subfolder/subsubfolder1
-  ./subfolder/subsubfolder2
-  ./subfolder/subsubfolder2/subsubsubfolder
```

I want to list this structure:

```
./fol'der/subfol'der/
```

Here is my code:

```
echo -n "" > myfile 
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I@ | cat | grep -v -P "^.$" | sed -e "s/'/\\\'/g" | xargs -I@ echo "-  @" >> myfile
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
-  ./fol'der
-  ./fol'der/subfol'der
```

But the output is:

```
-  ./fol'der
-  @
```

It seems like `sed` fails at the second occurrence of the single quote (`'`) character, or something. I have no idea. Can you help me? (I'm on OS X 10.7.4.)

Comment: Those meant to be samples, about directories using special characters.

Comment: You could probably simplify your example input and output and people would find it a whole lot easier to follow.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You are totally right. I was very tired last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I've been `grep`-ing and `sed`-ing like an idiot. Thought about a little bit, and I came up with a much more simple solution, a for loop.</del>

```
echo -n "" > myfile

for folder in $(find . -type d)
do
    if [[ $folder != "." ]]
    then
        echo "-  ${folder}" >> myfile
    fi
done
```

---

My previous solution wasn't working with names containing whitespaces, so the correct one is:

```
echo -n "" > myfile

find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' folder
do
    if [[ "${folder}" != "." ]]
    then
        echo "-  ${folder}" >> myfile
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
find . -type d -print0 | parallel -q -0 echo '-  '{}
```

Your output will be screwed up if you have any dirs with \n in its name. If you do not have any dirs with \n in the name you can do:

```
find . -type d -print | parallel -q echo '-  '{}
```

The -q is only needed if you *really* need two spaces after '-'.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

This is on Linux, but it should work on OS X:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I @ echo '- @'
```

It works for me regardless of whether the last set of quotes are single or double.

Output:

```
- ./fol'der
- ./fol'der/subfol'der
```